# React popover with boostrap doesnt show

Tags: jquery, reactjs, popover

Hello I need to use popover fucntion from Bootstrap (but normal bootstrap not React-Bootstrap) but somehow it isnt working for me and I cant figure out why.

I am using it like this.
In my render function I have this button

```
   <button id="mybutton" type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Popover msg" data-html="true">Popover on bottom</button>
```

In my myscript.js which is loaded properly I have

```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();    });
```

However it is not working when I click on the button. I also tried it like this

```
  $('#mybutton').popover();
```

No success. I have everything included Jquery, Boostrap.js and css and  I have put myscript.js at the end of index.html so none of js file can overwrite its functionality.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Or maybe it is not possible to use classis react popover in React?
Thank you

Comment: Mixing React + native JS does not seem to be a good idea... You risk to break the predictable state of usual React application and cause unexpected effects (especially if you use flux / redux).

Why not use https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#popovers (Bootstrap3) ?
Or https://reactstrap.github.io/components/popovers/ if you uses Bootstrap4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Actually I found out that using  `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` on document ready func. is still too early because my component still was not rendered. Therefore i put this script on `componentDidMount()` and now its working.